# How to get css and django working on live server

Tags: python, html, css, django

You guys were able to help me with last issue involving Django so I thought I'd ask another that has been killing me for the past couple days!

I have a small one app project with about 6 different pages, and I can get them to show however my style.css is not "showing" on the web page, I have followed countless guides including the Django's website and I just can't seem to get this working correctly. Here are some files that I think are relevant:

`public_html/mysite/nfl/templates/home.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title> Draftr Home Page </title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Using Bootstrap 3 framework with permission from getbootstrap.com -->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Style Sheet -->
    <link href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

style.css is located here `public_html/mysite/nfl/static` AND `/home/gobelogic/public_html/mysite/static`(alongside admin/)

`/home/gobelogic/public_html/mysite/mysite`:

```
import os.path
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#other
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'nfl'
)


TEMPLATE_DIRS = 
     "nfl/templates",

)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/gobelogic/public_html/mysite/nfl/static',
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
```

Ok I'm going to try and explain how I think django handles static files, please correct me where I'm wrong:

so in settings.py django is locating all static directories in my project and placing their contents in a single directory `static/` next to manange.py(which is done when I run `manage.py collectstatic`

in the html file I tell django to load all the static files so that i can use them at the top by using `{% load staticfiles %}` and then i say which one in particular by using `<link href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` by doing this, django uses the settings.py(?) to find where I put these static files and then loads up the stylesheet that way

Again I am running this on my production server so none of this is run through django built in server, idk if that matters or not

Thanks for any help

**EDIT** using django 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using Django internal server (rightly so), you need to make your production web server aware of the static file location. There is an example in Django docs for Apache (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files). Even if you are not using apache, generally you need to make sure that /static/ or whatever your STATIC_URL points to is served from the place where your STATIC_ROOT points to.

Comment: how do I know where `static_url` points to? shouldnt it just point to the static folder by the manage.py(where `static_root `points to)?

Comment: Both STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are in settings. Take a look at this page in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#settings-staticfiles

Comment: THANKS!!! I ended up getting it, I went to a2hosting(my hosting service) and they had a fairly straightforward solution, but I got it because of your direction so thanks again